# Cluster autoscaler scales down nodes when it is not supposed to

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

Cluster autoscaler scaled down our nodes even when we have the **scale-down-enabled** set to **false**

Is there any additional configuration needed to ensure scale down does not happen?

Comment: Please include your YAML files. It will make troublesooting easier.

Comment: Hi, these are the args I used to start the autoscaler

spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - ./cluster-autoscaler
        - --v=4
        - --stderrthreshold=info
        - --cloud-provider=aws
        - --skip-nodes-with-local-storage=false
        - --scale-down-enabled=false
        - --expander=least-waste
        - --node-group-auto-discovery=asg:tag=k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled

Comment: Did you fix this issue? Even I am facing issue with ` scale-down-enabled` set to false